# How do I create formula for counting diffrence between times

Tags: time

Can someone tell me how i can make arrival time counting (17:00) minus 22 minutes?

```
Arrival Time    Time On Bay Time Off Bay
17:00
```

So every time when I put something in, say "time" I will get "time minus 25 minutes" in arrival.

Comment: sorry let me write this once again

Comment: I need formula which is going automaticily minus 25 minutes for example if in cell a2 i have 17:00 i a3 i want 16:35?

Comment: Is this Excel or a specific programming language? Please click the "edit" link below your question to add relevant details and also more tags. This will help experts find this question and give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can do simple arithmetic on time values. The difference between two times is a (fractional) number of days. For example, 0.25 represents a time difference of 6 hours.

As such, you can add/subtract a (fractional) number of days to a time. Example:

- cell A1 is a fixed time value `17:00`
- cell A2 is a formula `=A1-0.25`; this will evaluate to `11:00`

To work with minutes, you will have to convert the amount of minutes to an amount of days; just divide the amount of minutes by 1440.

So a time difference of 25 minutes is represented by `25/1440`. Example:

- cell A1 is a fixed time value `17:00`
- cell A2 is a formula `=A1-25/1440`; this will evaluate to `16:35`